# "go to a wedding" vs "be in a wedding"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

How do you distinguish between "go to a wedding" and "be in a wedding" in Spanish? I would have thought "go to a wedding" would be "ir a una boda," but both duolingo and deepl.com translate it as "estar en una boda."  And deepl.com also translates "be in a wedding" as "estar en una boda."

Are they distinguished only by context?

Comment: The same difference in English applies in Spanish: go = ir, be = estar

Comment: @Catteau Google translate differentiates between go (ir) and be in (estar) a wedding.  I don't have access to duolingo, but I just tested deepl and also got the same as google (ir vs star).